# Is it possible to have e-mails archived instead of deleted in Exchange Server?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, email

I am using Exchange, but I am looking for a good way to create an e-mail archive. I would like to be able to search through my own files.

It seems that automatically placing all deleted e-mail in an Archive folder would be a good solution. Gmail does this wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

Commercial products like Symantec Enterprise Vault and competitors can do exactly this. What's your budget?

Comment: If you want a server side solution, then products like Enterprise Vault are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook comes with an AutoArchive function which allows rules to be set up for moving files to an archive PST.  You can set up a default and then override per folder if you want.

You can use the windows indexing/search functionality or there are quite a few 3rd party ones that will do Outlook and PSTs e.g. Lookeen

Comment: I am looking for a server-side solution, I currently already have like 10 backup PST files totalling 5GB because of reinstalls, it's worthless.